# Camel Retry Logic Based on particular Method

Tags: apache-camel

Does camel has retry function  based on particular part/method on Processor?.

I have implemented retry logic in our application and its retrying the whole processor.

Consider below diagram : A,B,C,D Nodes(Processor)

From---A---B---C---D

I am getting exception in C ,call goes back to B and then re execute the C.

I want to retry particular method on C .

Comment: what do you mean by particular method on c ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused here. A,B,C,D are endpoints or something else? The general idea would be to setup a header in message when C produces an error. Then you may have a choise when header X equals error route it to endpoint B else route it to endpoint D.

```
from("endpoint A")
            .to("endpoint B")
            .to("endpoint C")
            .process(new CProcessor())
            .choice()
            .when(header("Cerror").isEqualTo("true")).to("endpoint B")
            .otherwise()
            .to("endpoint D")
            .end();
```

Comment: A,B,C,D are action pipeline like sequence of Processor.